# ActiveMQ: handling of STOMP NACK messages

Tags: activemq

STOMP documentation says about NACK message

https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#NACK

> `NACK` is the opposite of `ACK`. It is used to tell the server that the client did not consume the message. The server can then either send the message to a different client, discard it, or put it in a dead letter queue. The exact behavior is server specific.

What does "server specific" actually mean in the context of ActiveMQ? Where can the behavior be set?